# Constraints for UITableView programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have one UITableView. I want to set constraints to it programmatically. Following are the constraints which I want to set.

1. Leading
2. Trailing
3. Top
4. Bottom

Comment: This is pretty standard situation. Have you read documentation on auto layout?

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraintSet = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:YourTableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:0.f];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint];
```

Now add this attributes also,

```
NSLayoutAttributeTop
NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
NSLayoutAttributeBottom
```

than add

```
[yourview addConstraint: constraintSet];
```

Answer (score 0):

In my code usually use the method like below, you can customize to your needs.

```
-(void)addConstraintForView:(UITableView*)tableView toView:(UIView*)parentView
{

NSMutableArray *constraints = [NSMutableArray new];
[constraints addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:parentView
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                   multiplier:1.0f
                                                     constant:0.0f]];

[constraints addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:parentView
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                   multiplier:1.0f
                                                     constant:0.0f]];

[constraints addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:parentView
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                   multiplier:1.0f
                                                     constant:0.0f]];

[constraints addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:parentView
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                   multiplier:1.0f
                                                     constant:0.0f]];

[parentView addConstraints:constraints];
}
```

Comment: What should i set here for "parentView". I am setting self.view
By setting self.view its not working.

Comment: I think your parentView is "self.view". When you have finished adding constraints try to update the layout of the view with " [self.view layoutSubviews];"

Answer (score 0):

You can the SnapKit pod library to add constrains programmatically. Here get [snapkit](http://snapkit.io/docs/)

```
import SnapKit

class YourViewController: UIViewController {

var tableView = UITableView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
       make.leading.equalTo(0)
       make.trailing.equalTo(self.view)
       make.top.equalTo(0)
       make.bottom.equalTo(0)
    }
}
}
```